# Как в классе ошибки обратиться к переменной другого класса?

Tags: python, классы, переменные

Допустим, у нас есть такой код:

```
class Example(object):

    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg

    class MyError(Exception):
        def __init__(self, errorin):
            self.errorin = errorin

        def __str__(self):
            return "Error in %s" % self.errorin
            sys.exit()

    def plus(self, num):
        try:
            return self.arg + num
        except:
            raise self.MyError(what_to_write_here) from None
            sys.exit()
```

Достаточно написать что-то на месте `what_to_write_here` или надо переделывать весь код?

Comment: Во-первых, не совсем понятно, зачем нужен внешний класс `Example`. Во-вторых, в принципе непонятно, зачем нужно что-то переписывать? И так все нормально.

Comment: И в третьих: избегайте излишней нагруженности кода. `"Error in %s" % self.errorin` понять с первого взгляда гораздо сложнее, чем `"Error in " + self.errorin"`. Подобное форматирование хорошо в случае нескольких переменных.

Comment: Глеб, может, классы и не нужны. Но мне надо случай именно с классами. Вы меня неправильно поняли. Допустим, я создаду переменную `x = Example(1)` и попробую выполнить операцию `x.plus("2")`. Как сделать так, чтобы в ошибке MyError, которая будет вызывается из-за TypeError, было написано "Error in x"?

Comment: Очевидно, написать `'x'` вместо `what_to_write_here`.

Comment: А как программе узнать, что переменная называется `'x'`, а не как-то по другому?

Comment: Не понял. В смысле как? Из кода, разумеется. Подставьте, запустите и посмотрите.

Comment: @Глеб, а как сделать автоподставление?

Comment: Если вам нужно будет менять название ошибки, сделайте в ее классе особый атрибут для этого с значением по умолчанию.